# Java Multimap search for value

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I have a Multimap and need to search for the values.
It looks like this

```
ListMultiMap<String, Person> pers =  ArrayListMultimap.create();
....
Person person = new Person();
person.setName(name);
peson.setAge(age);
person.setId(id);
...
pers.put(name, person);
```

I need the name as a key, and it should be possible to add e.g. two Persons with Name "Bob". The ID should be unique.

For Example:

```
Name: Bob, ID:1
Name: Bob, ID:2
```

I know how to get the values for the key "Bob" out of the map.
But how can I get only the values for Bob with the ID 1?

Comment: `ListMultiMap` is from which library?

Comment: It's from the Google Collections Library

Comment: The `ListMultiMap` `get` function will return you a collection of values where the key is 'Bob'. All you have to do then is loop through that collection of Person objects and query which one has an ID of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will retrieve the person Bob with an ID of 1:

```
ListMultiMap<String, Person> pers =  ArrayListMultimap.create();
List<Person> persons = pers.get("Bob");
for(Person p : persons){
    if (p.getId() == 1){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is doing what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, the `get(String key)` method of `ListMultiMap` will return a `List` of elements for the given key. Since your `person.id` is not part of the key, it will not have any impact on the returned list.

As I.K. said in the accepted answer, you can simply iterate over the returned list to get the person with the given ID.

However a better suited data structure might be the [Guava `Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html), that allows you to have 2 keys (you can also think of if as a sort of `Map` of `Map`s, or in your case `Map<String,Map<Long, Person>>`) :

```
Table<String, Long, Person> personsByNameAndId = HashBasedTable.create();
Person bob = ...;
//put it in the table
personsByNameAndId.put(bob.getName(), bob.getId(), bob);

//lookup by name and ID
Person bobWithId1 = personsByNameAndId.get("Bob", 1l);

//get all Bobs
Collection<Person> allPersonsNamedBob = personsByNameAndId.row("bob").values();

//get person with ID=2 regardless of name
Person personWithId2 = personsByNameAndId.column(2l).values().iterator().next();
```

Answer (score 1):

While the checked answer is correct, I think the all-guava solution is more elegant:

```
   Multimap<String, Person> pers =  ArrayListMultimap.create();
   Person firstBob = FluentIterable.from(pers.get("Bob")).firstMatch(new Predicate<Person>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Person p) {
            return p.getId() == 1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you read the Guava page on the caveats of functional programming?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Louis - for everybody who is interested, here is the link: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained